# Secure Certificate complete installation

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate

I have recently installed an ssl certificate on my asp.net website. A check of the installation shows that the installation was done correctly. The problem is that, the url is still showing http: instead of http**s**:. i have tried all that I can including activating ssl support in my hosting settings but to no avail and google really isnt helping on how to get that "s". My assumption which is now obviously wrong was that the "s" comes automatically after ssl installation.

Comment: Did you add binding to your website with https? If not, please do that to get https in url

Comment: i was supposed to just force all http requests to https, its just a matter of redirecting in web.config